# Send logs to Slack from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, slack

Is it possible to redirect logs from the built in `logging` module to a Slack channel, rather than stdout or a file.

I was thinking there might be some way to do this using the Slack [API client](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient):

```py
import logging
from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_token = 'MY-TOKEN-HERE'
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

logging.basicConfig(...)  # Some slack magic???

logging.debug('This message should go to a slack channel')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Comment: Maybe using a [`SocketHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#sockethandler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package ‘slack-log-handler’ on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/slacker-log-handler/).

It contains a ‘LogHandler’ which can be used by the python logging module.

Comment: I enjoyed slacker-log-handler, for quite some time. However, it appears to be a dead project now (Oct. '20). It forces `six` back to 1.11.0, which broke `pip` in my python 3.8 virtual environments. It also leverages the [slacker python slack library](https://github.com/os/slacker) which itself is archived/deprecated. If you go that route, Caveat Emptor.